# how to auto generate a number in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
page    id
1       a1
1       a2
1       a3
2       a4
2       a5
2       a6
3       a7
3       a8
3       a9
```

`

what i need to know is how to auto generate a number 'page' like that ? So it means a1 a2 a3 is on page 1, a4 a5 a6 is on page 2, and a7 a8 a9 is on page 3

i've tried using this query

```
set @num:=0; 
select id,  @num:=@num+1 `Row` from promos;
```

then the result is

```
page    id
1       a1
2       a2
3       a3
4       a4
5       a5
6       a6
7       a7
8       a8
9       a9
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CEIL(MID(id,2)/3) as pages,id FROM promos;
```

Comment: Wel-come dude...:(

Answer (score 1):

1. Write your own function to generate new ID.
2. Automate it with MyISAM table engine + AUTO_INCREMENT

From the MySQL documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

Read more here - [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)